# Why gcc gives warning: implicit declaration of function qsort_r?

Tags: c, gcc

I do `include<stdlib.h>` where qsort_r is given. And I use `gcc -std=c99 -O3 myfun.c -o myfun` to compile.

It compiles, links and runs well. I don't know why I got this warning and what is potential risk of this warning ?

BTW, my compiler is `gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does so because you use `-std=c99` , there's no qsort_r function in stdlib.h in c99.

Use `-std=gnu99` to make the extensions available, or add a `#define _GNU_SOURCE` to your source files before including the header files.

Answer (score 2):

`qsort_r` is not supported by C99. Specification says nothing about it.

### [Language Standards Supported by GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.4/gcc/Standards.html#Standards):

> By default, **GCC provides some extensions to the C language that on rare occasions conflict with the C standard**<sub>1</sub>. See Extensions to the C Language Family. Use of the -std options listed above will disable these extensions where they conflict with the C standard version selected. You may also select an extended version of the C language explicitly with -std=gnu89 (for C89 with GNU extensions) or -std=gnu99 (for C99 with GNU extensions). The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu89; this will change to -std=gnu99 in some future release when the C99 support is complete. Some features that are part of the C99 standard are accepted as extensions in C89 mode.

---

<sub>1. Emphasis is mine</sub>